# Cannot find Device Choose Button in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have used Android Studio for several weeks，I use my iPhone to Flutter Attach .
Today I create a new Project, I cannot find the Device Choose Button, Where is the button to Change Device ?

As the Pictures below, I have Two projects, another Project has the "Device Choose Button"

[image]

Comment: You can still choose your device from the Device Manager (fourth button from the right)

Answer (score 0):

- Close the project
- Restart your IDE
- Do it several times [4-5 times]